# App rejected due to Guideline 3.1.2 - Business - Payments - Subscriptions

Tags: macos, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval, in-app-subscription, auto-renewable

My macOS app is continuously rejected due to the auto-renewing subscription.

This is what Apple reviewer said to me:

> Guideline 3.1.2 - Business - Payments - Subscriptions
>
> Your app uses auto-renewing subscriptions, but it is not an appropriate use of the service.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please change your in-app purchase product to a non-renewing subscription.

This makes no sense for me because the iOS version of the same app is approved and it has exactly the same data for the auto-renewing subscription.
I have asked for more information but they don't answer me.

Can anybody help me or give me some clue to understand what may be happening?

Thanks for your time.

PS: Both versions of the app (iOS and macOS) were reviewed at the same time :p iOS approved, macOS rejected. It is a productivity app with a seven days free trial.

Comment: Apple constantly update their guidelines. What was okay in the past must not necessarily be okay in the future (I am encountering a similiar problem with one of my apps where I can no longer provide updates). But I think the answer you got from Apple is pretty straightforward. Simply update your subscription to a non-renewing one and you should be good to go. What kind of app / subscription is it?

Comment: Hi. Both versions of the app (iOS and macOS) were reviewed at the same time  :p   iOS approved, macOS rejected.It is a productivity app with a seven days free trial.

Comment: Have a look at this page: https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/apple-will-reject-your-subscription-app-if-you-dont-include-this-disclosure-bba95244405d Does your iOS app provide any additional information about the subscription that your macOS version is lacking?

Comment: Thank you, I had already read this page looking for information about in-app purchases months ago.The two apps have the same information, description, the same in-app purchase metadata. In fact, it's a Mac Catalyst app and you could say that they are the same app.

Comment: Hi @TomeuMascó, did you eventually get your auto-renew subscription through the app review? I’m running into the same app review rejection,while my competitor’s app is able to utilise apple’s auto-renew subscription infrastructure. Doesn’t make sense at all.

Comment: Hi @OngPeHon, I'm afraid not :( After two weeks we gave up and ended up releasing the mac version with non-renewal subscriptions, while the iOS version had auto-renew subscriptions.

Comment: thanks for the update! @TomeuMascó

Comment: Any updates on this issue? I had same issue with subscription setup for my iOS app yesterday. And I do not know what to do now.